# The Sinc Function and the Partition of Unity Property

Tags: fourier-transform

For this question purposes a function, $ f \left( t \right) $ is said to hold the Partition of Unity if:

$$ \forall t, \ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f \left ( t - n \right ) = 1 $$

Using the Poisson Summation Formula the Partition of Unity is equivalent of $ F \left( 2 \pi k \right ) = \delta \left ( k \right ) $ where $ F \left ( \omega \right ) $ is the Fourier Transform of $ f \left ( t \right ) $.

Looking at
$$ \frac{ \operatorname{sinc}^{p} \left ( pt \right ) }{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}^{p} \left ( pt \right ) } $$
Does it holds the Partition of Unity for $ p \geq 2 $?

At first I thought it does, since the Fourier Transform equivalent property will hold.
Yet it seems I'm missing something.
Any ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *any* finite-energy signal $x(t)$, the function 
$$y(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(t-nT), -\infty < t < \infty$$
is a *periodic* function of $t$ with period $T$, that is, $y(t-T) = y(t), -\infty < t < \infty$. Note that $T$ is not necessarily the *least* period of $y(t)$.  Now, a periodic
function can be expressed as a Fourier series 
$$y(t) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty c_m \exp(j2\pi mt/T)$$ where
$$\begin{align}
c_m &= \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T y(t)\exp(-j2\pi mt/T)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(t-nT)\exp(-j2\pi mt/T)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^T  x(t-nT)\exp(-j2\pi mt/T)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{-nT}^{-(n-1)T}  x(s)\exp(-j2\pi ms/T)\,\mathrm ds\\
&=  \frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  x(s)\exp(-j2\pi ms/T)\,\mathrm ds\\
&= \frac{1}{T}X\left(\frac{m}{T}\right)
\end{align}$$
where $X(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(t)$.
Now, for the case $T = 1$, 
if $y(t) = 1$ for all $t$ as the OP desires, then it must be that $c_0 = 1$
and $c_m = 0$ for all $m\neq 0$, and therefore the Fourier transform of $x(t)$
must have the property that
$$X(m) = \begin{cases} 1, & m = 0,\\ 0, &m \neq 0,\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
that is, $X(f)$ is what is sometimes referred to as a *Nyquist pulse* (in the
frequency domain). We are familiar with Nyquist pulses in the time domain,
with $\operatorname{sinc}(t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$ being the most
familiar one,  but there are many others, including as a special case
$[\operatorname{sinc}(t)]^k$. Applying duality, 
$X(f) = [\operatorname{sinc}(f)]^k$ is a Nyquist
pulse in the frequency domain, and its inverse Fourier transform $x(t)$ is
a signal with the property that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(t-nT) = 1, -\infty < t < \infty.$$
Note that $x(t)$ is the $k$-fold convolution of $\operatorname{rect}(t)$
with itself. For example, with $k = 2$,
$$x(t) = \begin{cases}1 - |t|, &-1 < t < 1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
What about the other way around?  Well, $\operatorname{sinc}(t)$ has
Fourier transform $\operatorname{rect}(f)$ which has the Nyquist pulse
property $(1)$ in the frequency domain as does $[\operatorname{sinc}(t)]^2$
whose Fourier transform
$$X(f) = \begin{cases}1 - |f|, &-1 < f < 1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
also satisfies $(1)$.  However, for $k > 2$, 
the Fourier transform of $[\operatorname{sinc}(t)]^k$ **does not**
have the Nyquist pulse property $(1)$ because the three-fold (or more
generally $k$-fold convolution of $\operatorname{rect}(f)$ with itself
does not satisfy $(1)$: the $k$-fold convolution "bulges" outside
the interval $(-1,1)$.  See for, example, the 
*[Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution)*
for details of the exact values of the convolution results.

Comment: I see what you meant. I'm after the proof that these family of Sinc's is "Nyquist Pulse".

Comment: @Drazick Unfortunately the family does not have the right properties except when $k$ (or $p$ as you called it) has value $1$ or $2$. I have added this information to the end of my answer.

Comment: I think it doesn't hold for p=2 as well. The scaling at time works twice (Scaling and the Power). I was given to prove they do hold it and I think the question was wrong.

Comment: I just gave an argument above that it _does_ hold for $p=2$ but not for $p > 2$. Feel free to edit my calculations to correct what you claim is a mistake in my answer, or down-vote it if you prefer.

Comment: The normalized sinc^2(2t) doesn't hold, I think. The convolution extends its support as you pointed. You didn't take into account the scaling account which stretches it further (form -2 to 2 in you example). Am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't say $\operatorname{sinc}^2(2t)$, I said $[\operatorname{sinc}(t)]^2$, which is not the same.

Comment: Yet I asked for sinc^p(pt) which does't hold for p=2 and above. I think... That was my problem, I was asked to prove it and saw it was wrong. If you could address the scaling factor as well as the power I'd be happy (And close the question). Thank You!!!